# Uploading ensutils,js to geth console

Tags: go-ethereum, ens

I am trying to upload ensutils.js from https://github.com/ethereum/ens to my geth console. I am using `loadScript('/home/path/to/ensutils.js')`.

Every time I try it, it gives me an invalid address error and I am not sure why. Would anyone happen to know what the issue is here. I have my default address set and the account unlocked.

```
loadScript('/home/path/to/ensutils.js')
```

Comment: Please post exactly the line how you're calling loadScript.

Comment: i used the same syntax for the ensutils-test.js and it uploads with out the invalid address error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ensutils.js, there is for example a code line like `var ens = ensContract.at('0x314159265dd8dbb310642f98f50c066173c1259b');`.

When your node is not synced to the mainnet, this line will fail.

Comment: My console has been running for severail days, when i do eth.syncing the highest block and current block are almost the same, how do i know if it is done syncing or not? I ran that line of code in my console and it returned undefined, so i am guessing you are right

Comment: I am also unable to unlock eth.accounts[0].

Comment: I tried this on a geth console of a node which is synced with the *mainnet*. It worked. You can copy&paste ``var ensContract = ...`` and ``var ens = ensContract.at...`` directly to the console and see what happens.

Comment: After running both lines, they both returned undefined

Comment: That's ok. What happens if you type ``ens`` in the console?

Comment: It shows list of functions. The method i would like to communicate with is the ethRegistrat auctionRegistrarContract.at(ens.owner(namehash('eth')))

Comment: ens.owner(namehash('eth')) returns "0x" I believe this is when there invalid address error is coming from

Comment: My end goal is to use ethRegistrar.entries(web3.sha3('name')). I have ethRegistrar uploaded but when i use the command above, it returns invalid address.

Comment: Technicall you answered the question. I will post again aboutthe ethRegistrat.